# Console Command to inhibit screensaver?

Tags: 11.10, screensaver

Is there any console command to inhibit the screensaver in Ubuntu 11.10?

I don't want to have indicators like Caffeine for every function I need.

In Gnome 2.x it was something like `gnome-screensaver --inhibit`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the stuff :

```
gconftool --set --type=bool /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled False
```

thus, you will disable the gnome-screensaver.

If you want to reactivate it after :

```
gconftool --set --type=bool /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled True
```